# How to fail the build on missing hidden dependencies in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

The codebase consists of hundreds of solutions with a couple of C# projects each, all of which are configured to copy their output DLLs into a specific folder from where other projects can then reference them.

Projects (= DLLs) sometimes have hidden dependencies in the form of third-party nuget packages which are resulting in a runtime exception if the nuget package is not installed in the executed project. Is there a built-in (or just any way really) to denote the existence of these hidden dependencies without explicitly passing in the required classes from the third party library and fail the build if the packages are not installed?

An example:

Project Company.ExternalClient provides a wrapper around StackOverflow.Redis, providing a HiddenRedisClient class.

Project SomeMicroService references the Company.ExternalClient dll to use the HiddenRedisClient class, but does not reference the StackOverflow.Redis nuget package. It will compile but fail at run-time which is the issue here.

Comment: Deliver the projects as nuget packages rather than dlls. Then use the nugets in other projects and it will get the required dependencies.

Comment: I believe there is a warning? Can you confirm and than fail build on warning?